# "Require is not defined" Error on RaspberryPi with node v14.7.0

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, raspberry-pi, referenceerror

Currently, I am facing wired Issue.. because somehow I can't execute my index.js on my Raspberry PI which has node v14.7.0 installed. And nodeJs should actually provide 'require'.

**Note: On my windows engine everything is working quite fine with node v12.13.0.**

**How I generate my js files**
I am using TypeScript and so I generate a dist Folder..
where the index.js looks at the end like this (see below)

File Structure

[image]

index.js Code

```
"use strict";
var exports = {}; // Fixes Exports is not defined Error
Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", { value: true });
var event_scheduler_1 = require("./schedulers/event-scheduler"); // <-- Error happens here
console.log("Start cakedash-backend");
event_scheduler_1.startEventScheduler();
```

Error:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Ok fixed the issue with help of
https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/33741

You have to remove in the package.json the **"type": "module"**